# how does apple jdk6 acquire system encoding?

Tags: encoding, java-8

In apple jdk6 if we get default charset, it returns for example, gb2313,if we set system language to chinese. But openjdk returns utf-8.
How does JDK 6 get the map info from the encoding to the language?
Iam running the java app in a bundle,however, in IDEA, the jdk jvm returns utf-8.

Comment: Why do you tag a question about “jdk6” with `[java-8]`?

Comment: because, on Apple JDK 6  returns the encoding, while oralcle JDK 8 returns UTF-8.

Comment: Perhaps, you are asking the wrong question. Do you really want to know “*how does apple jdk6 acquire system encoding?*” or rather “*How can I make OpenJDK 8 use gb2313 instead of utf-8?*” These questions are not connected. Whatever “apple jdk6” does, is not necessarily applicable to “OpenJDK 8”. And what the latter does, seems to be the right thing anyway. All resources I could find, tell that the system encoding of MacOS X *is* UTF-8…

Comment: Thanks for the help. I created a hard code mapping between languages and encodings to mimic the behavior. I checked the code of OpenJDK, it calls setlocale then use nl_langinfo() to get encoding info and put it into system props "file.encoding". However, I have not tested on OpenJDK. I think the workaround works now.